# How to convert a number to Q format

Tags: c, embedded

I am working with XMC1300 MCU series from Infineon. For my application I need to find out the square root of some data.

Following are the math lib api provided by Infineon

```
int16_t XMC_MATH_CORDIC_Q15_Sqrt(int16_t x) 
int32_t XMC_MATH_CORDIC_Q31_Sqrt(int32_t x)
```

These two API accept and returns data format Q15 and Q31 i.e. It could only represent [-1,1] range.

Suppose I wanted to find out the square root of

```
144
200
1000
34567
50000
```

How can I change these numbers in range [-1, 1].

What needs to be done for the normalization of Input and Output.

Regards,
Tinchu

Comment: So the two functions you mention can determine squre roots for value in the range from -1 to 1 and you want to use them for calculating for values from 0 to 50000? For understanding better, I would like to know what the result of type "int" would be for -0.25. Otherwise normalising should be done be dividing by the square of a known number (i.e. devide by 90000 or something closer to 50000), then multiply the result be the known number (300). If you provide a little mcve around your problem I will make an answer with code.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanx for your kind reply

Comment: https://www.infineonforums.com/threads/5210-Math-Cordic-Square-root-API?s=d10133f31beb6a28a7bf2efa0f2b098d

Comment: Above is the link for the Infineon forum. Please open it. Reply over there is not satisfactory. As per my understading, these two API only accepts arguments with format Q15 and Q31 and returns the result in the same format. So if I want the square root of any number say 57. I need to first convert it to format Q15 or Q31. But how do we do it?

Comment: Multiply by a power of four to scale to a large value within the range of the source operand (int16_t or int32_t).  Call the function.  Divide the result by the same power of two, performing the division in some suitable data type.

Comment: @Chris thanx for your kind reply. How will I convert any number to Q15 or Q31 format? Like 200, if I multiply with int16_t range i.e. 32768, the product will be greater than 32768.

Comment: 32768 / 200 = 163.84 should I use this in any kind of calculation?

Comment: Please read again, "Multiply by a power of four to scale to a large value within the range of the source operand" - not multiply *by* the range, multiply by a power of four which gives a result **within the range**

Answer (score 2):

You can't represent 144 or 50000 directly in Q15 or Q31 format.  As you mention, those formats are fixed point representations of numbers between -1 and 1.

So the problem you are left with is a basic math problem.
We can use the fact that

> sqrt(A/B) = sqrt(A) / sqrt(B)

Let's do the example where your value `A = 144`:
Set B to the Q31 divisor `B = 0x7FFFF =  32768`

```
A/B = 0.00439`
Sqrt(A/B) = 0.0663 
Sqrt(B) = Sqrt(32768) = 181.02
Sqrt(A) = Sqrt(A/B)*Sqrt(B) = 0.0663 * 181.02 = 12.
```

How to do this with Q15 numbers? All numbers are scaled by `B`.
So Sqrt(A/B) is simply `XMC_MATH_CORDIC_Q15_Sqrt(A) //=> 2172`
because 0.0663 = 2172/32768.

Sqrt(B) is 181. The final result in integer math is `181 * 2172 / 32768 = 12` *

For larger numbers you need to use the Q31 divisor: 
`0x7fffFFFF =  2147483647`

*note: Integer math will round that answer down to 11. If you want better rounding, you'll need to examine bit 15 before you do the divide.

Comment: thanx for your kind reply.

Comment: A = 144, XMC_MATH_CORDIC_Q15_Sqrt(A) //=> 2172, how you get this value. Because I am getting 3117 when I am passing 144 to the API. Moreover if we take other cases like 200 or 1000 how will this work?

Comment: I don't know why you are getting 3117.  What do you get for 0x4000?

Comment: For 0x4000 I am getting 23170

Comment: 23170/32768 = 0.707 = sqrt(0.5) so that makes sense.  Still not sure where  3117 comes from That should be result for 308.

Comment: for 308 it is coming 3619

Answer (score 2):

I usually just develop formulas to convert from machine to engineering units.  In this case the input and output would be expected to be Q15.  Below I use _eu to designate engineering units, _mu to designate machine units and sqrt() to designate the actual square root.  The formula for square root:

```
output_eu = sqrt(input_eu)
```

Conversions for input and output:

```
output_mu = (2^15)*output_eu
input_mu = (2^15)*input_eu
```

To get the equivalent calculation in machine units, substitute:

```
output_mu/(2^15) = sqrt(input_mu/(2^15))
output_mu = sqrt((2^15)*input_mu)
```

It's best to right shift the input in order to optimize precision, so in the case of 144, the number could be left shifted by 7 bits:  144*(2^7) = 18432

So the input is basically Q7.

In other words:

```
output_mu = sqrt((2^15)*((2^7)*input_eu))
          = (2^11)*sqrt(input_eu)
```

So basically the output here is Q11 and could be shifted right 11 bits to get to the result in engineering units.

So if you were to execute this in code, lets say value 144 is loaded into variable x and we want to put result in variable y:

```
y = x << 7;
y = XMC_MATH_CORDIC_Q15_Sqrt(y);
y >>= 11;
```

Walking through the math:

```
1) y = (144*(2^7)) = 18432
2) y = sqrt((2^15)*18432) = 24576
3) y = 24576/(2^11) = 12
```

Comment: Using `^` _in C code_  to represent exponentiation is confusing as `^` is the exclusive-or operator.  Post lacks clarity when it is switching from code to/from math.  Consider other formats.

Comment: Jonathon, chux thanx alot for your kind reply

Comment: Also how this comes? output_mu = sqrt((2^15)*((2^7)*input_eu))
          = (2^11)*sqrt(input_eu).            (2^7) how it comes in tha calculation

Comment: If the number is greater than int16_t we will have to jump for int32_t which is Q31. In this case what will be the bit shifting calculations

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply.  Here is my response to the second comment.  For the example case of sqrt(144), prior to calculating the square root it is desirable to left shift 144 until it occupies 14 bits.  This will maximize the overall precision of the calculation, since more bits will be populated in the output of the calculation.

Comment: Regarding the fourth comment, you should only need to use the Q31 square root if the input is larger than 16384 (2^14).  If more precision is required in the output, however, you may want to consider using the Q31 square root.